# WiX: Define made in included file not avaible from wxs-fragment-file

Tags: wix

I have a `defines.wxi`-file which contains some good definitions used in all my wxs-files.

When I attempt to reference the defined value from one of the `<Fragment>`-files I get `Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.IMAGE_FOLDER)'` back in my face.

I guess there is something trivial I am missing here...
Any ideas?

**Edit 19:th April.**
Found that issue only occurs if reference from a Fragment-file.
Re-wrote sample to match that.

---

**defines.wxi**

```
<Include>
    <?define IMAGE_FOLDER="Images" ?> 
</Include>
```

**some-Fragment.wxs**

```
<Fragment>
  <?Include defines.wxi ?>

  <Component Id='c.Images' Guid=".." Directory='INSTALLDIR.Images' >
     <File Id='f.sample.jpg' Source='$(var.IMAGE_FOLDER)sample.jpg' Name='sample.jpg' />
  </Component>
```

Comment: Found that the sample above was to simplified.issue only occurs if reference from a Fragment-file. Re-wrote sample to match that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it.

Where it in the sample says:

```
<?Include defines.wxi ?>
```

it should be **lower case**...

```
<?include defines.wxi ?>
```

then it works like a charm!

/L

Answer (score 1):

Ok, another try. 
Do you reference anything in that `<Fragment/>` from the main `<Product/>` ? The contents of the fragment are visible to the rest of the code in case you reference anything from it. For instance, you can reference a component (`<ComponentRef/>`) or component group (`<ComponentGroupRef/>`). Once anything is referenced, the entire fragment is included.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why yes.
In my main-feature in Product I have a ComponentRef to my component c.Images.

However, I don't think we have come that far. The error message comes from the WiX-compiler candle, not from the linker.
So WiX believes that it is pre-processor error.

Comment: Yeah, that's right... I ran out of ideas...
Did you try to upgrade to WiX 3.0 RTM if you're not using it?

Answer (score 0):

In the text of the error message you provided it says "Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.**MAGE_FOLDER**)'", not $(var.**IMAGE_FOLDER**) - the leading **'I'** is missing. This made me think that you reference the same variable somewhere in the rest of your code, but misspelling it.

In this case, the candle.exe is absolutely right - it can find IMAGE_FOLDER, but can't find MAGE_FOLDER.

Hope this is the case and you'll fix it quickly. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but it was really IMAGE_FOLDER in the error-message. The tyop was in the question.